# Use alias as parameter

Tags: bash, terminal, parameters, alias

on linux terminal i would like to be able to use an alias as a parameter, and not for a single command, the same parameter for all commands.

for example instead of doing `git push origin HEAD` I can do:

```
alias H='HEAD'

git push origin H
```

Is it just for example, can I create placeholders for commands or parameters outside of Git as well?

Answer (score 1):

`bash` aliases don't work this way. They are only expanded when they occur in command position, or following an alias expansion that ends in a space.

However, what you really want (in this example, anyway) is for *Git* to recognize `H` as an alias for `HEAD`, which you can accomplish by creating a new symbolic reference named `H` that refers to `HEAD`.

```
git symbolic-ref H HEAD
```

Comment: One wonders if OP really wants this, or just to set `push.default=simple` in config.